# Horizontal div height not growing according to another

Tags: html, height

I have a html file. It have two  tags. My problem is first  height is not growing according to second. I have given a border-right to first . If anyone run the below html, find the problem.Here i'm attaching the code .

```
 <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}

html {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}

</style>
<title>
</title>
<head>
<body>
<div style="height:150px">
<div class="one">
<h1>Heading Here</h1>
</div>

<div style="height:100px"></div>

<div style="width:675px">
    <div style="border-right:1px dotted #2093E8;width:335px;height:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden;float:left;vertical-align:top;top: 0px;">
            <div style="float:left;width:315px;">
                <a href="/Category/1/Sports" class="latest_title" target="_blank">SPORTS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="common_text" style="float:left;width:315px;padding-right:1px;padding-top:18px;">
                <div style="float:left;width:325px;padding-top:2px;padding-right:8px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                    <p><a href="/News/Sports/1/Sachin-Tendulkar-out-after-scoring-just-10" class="read_more2 common_text common_text1" target="_blank">Sachin Tendulkar out after scoring just 10;<!--CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case--></a><!--<a href="story.php?id=141762" class="read_more2 common_text common_text1">CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case</a>--></p>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left;width:315px;padding-right:20px;line-height:19px;">
                    <div style="float:left;width:315px;">
                        <p style="padding-left:0px"><spam class="common_text common_text2" style="text-align:justify">Sachin Tendulkar out after scoring just 10<!--CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case--></spam></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="height:12px;clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="border-left:0px dotted #2093E8;width:335px;overflow:hidden;float:right;vertical-align:top;top: 0px;">
        <div style="float:left;width:315px;">
            <a href="/Category/2/Politics" class="latest_title" target="_blank">POLITICS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="common_text" style="float:left;width:315px;padding-right:1px;padding-top:18px;">
            <div style="float:left;width:325px;padding-top:2px;padding-right:8px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                <p><a href="/News/Politics/6/Dikshit-doesn-t-rule-out-alliance-with-AAP" class="read_more2 common_text common_text1" target="_blank">Dikshit doesn't rule out alliance with AAP;<!--CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case--></a><!--<a href="story.php?id=141762" class="read_more2 common_text common_text1">CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case</a>--></p>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left;width:315px;padding-right:20px;line-height:19px;">
                <div style="float:left;width:315px;">
                    <p style="padding-left:0px"><spam class="common_text common_text2" style="text-align:justify">New Delhi: Delhi Chief Minister Sheila Dikshit Thursday said she has not ruled out an alliance with the Aam Aadmi Party (AAP), in the possibility of a hung assembly in Delhi which goes to polls Dec 4.

'Won't comment on alliance with AAP. I didn't <!--CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case--></spam></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height:12px;clear:both"></div>
        <div style="float:left;width:315px;padding-top:8px;"><a style="float:left;background:url(Images/testImg/sprite_new.png) no-repeat 0px -422px;padding-left:0.88em;" class="common_text common_text7 color5 rdmor" href="/News/Politics/5/Italian-Marines-case-won-t-be-resolved-by-Christma" target="_blank"><!--CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case-->Italian Marines case won't be resolved by Christma</a></div>
        <div style="float:left;width:315px;padding-top:8px;"><a style="float:left;background:url(Images/testImg/sprite_new.png) no-repeat 0px -422px;padding-left:0.88em;" class="common_text common_text7 color5 rdmor" href="/News/Politics/2/MP-Congress-leader-commits-suicide-after-being-de" target="_blank"><!--CBI, Kerala get SC notice in ice cream parlour sex case-->MP: Congress leader commits suicide after being de</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>


<body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Bobbin

Comment: If you want help, you need build a good css with id and class. and create a codepen or jsfiddle =)

Comment: Please help me to create a good css. From where i need to start

Comment: put your css just in your <head><style></style></head> or in other file style.css. Don't put your css ===> bad example => <div style="...">